# CRM 4 - Add Account specific field to Opportunity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

My Account entity has an Account Manager field. I would like to add this same field to Opportunity as a reference. Is there a way to add this field to Opportunity and make it point to the attribute "Account.Account Manager"?

I am using MS Dynamics CRM 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is copying the field "Account Manager" in entity "Account" to entity "Opportunity", is it?

If that is what you want, you need to create a field named "Account Manager" (or whatever you wish to) in the "Opportunity" entity form; the field type being the same. And you need to have some kind of workflow/plugin/javascript to update the field in "Opportunity" form with the same value as present in the "Account" form.

EDIT: Based on your comment, I've edited the answer. You can achieve it by two means:

1. Have some kind of workflow/plugin populating the field in
   Opportunity form from that of the Account form.
2. Fetch the value of the Account field by javascript on Opportunity
   form load and display it in a field.

Also, you might want to make the field read-only in Opportunity form.

Comment: I do not want to copy the field's data. I just want to display it on the "Opportunity" form (and Account), and have the data be stored in the Account entity.

Comment: You cannot show a field of Account in Opportunity form directly. The workaround is to create a similar field in the Opportunity form and populate it with the value from that of the Account field. See the approaches above in my answer.

Comment: I would go with onLoad + javascript. How do I reference the Account Manager's name (account manager is a lookup field to contact)?

Comment: @SkeetSkeet You can form a fetchXML query and execute it. If I were to provide a pseudo-query it would look something like - 'select Account Manager from Account where AccountId = <yourAccountLookupIdInOpportunityForm>'. You can have a look here to see how to execute a fetchXML query http://techdetector.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/fetch-xml-and-javascript-in-crm-4-0/ Also use the fetchXML builder for CRM 4.0 to generate the XML.